PCA Reconstruction Properties
Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ be our data matrix where $n$ is the number of examples and $d$ is the feature dimension. Applying PCA to $X$, we get a low-dimensional representation $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}$ where $l$ is the output dimension. Let $X_\mathrm{recon}$ be the PCA reconstruction of $X$.
The question has two parts:

If all entries of $X$ are non-negative, can $X_\mathrm{recon}$ ever have non-negative entries?
Is the sum of any row of $X$ always the same as the sum of the corresponding row of $X_\mathrm{recon}$? For motivation, if $X$ is a sample of probability distributions (meaning all rows sum to $1$), will the reconstruction rows also sum to $1$?

I was reading this paper which claims:

PCA is a purely geometric process; it has no notion of the original data as probability
distributions, and is therefore free to generate reconstructions of the data that contain
negative numbers or do not sum to 1.

However, I was playing around with some empirical simulations and noticed that both (1) and (2) were always true even when I generated high dimensional data with few samples and only a single component. I'm struggling to come up with a counterexample for (1) and (2) that corresponds to the paper's claim.

This is not a claim! Given $X$ all PCA does is to find a projection of $X$, $P_UX$ into some subspace $U$ that minimizes $\lVert X - P_U X \rVert^2_F$. This construction is purely geometric.

@TedBlack, but probability has a well-studied geometry too (the simplex). I understand the definition of PCA as minimizing the squared Frobenius norm. What I'm looking for is either a proof of the claims or (more likely) a counter example.

Also, for what it's worth, PCA does have a probabilistic interpretation as a MLE problem with Gaussian noise.

I am not so sure that the first question is false. Projection is a contraction so projecting onto any subspace actually moves every column of $X$ closer to the mean, which is itself a positive vector

I ran some Python simulations and found an answer:
Claim 1
Let $$X = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 49 \\
69 & 90 \\
26 & 99 
\end{bmatrix} . $$
Then applying PCA with $1$ component and reconstructing yields
$$
X_{\mathrm{recon}} \approx \begin{bmatrix}
-3.2 & 55.2 \\
62.2 & 100 \\
37.1 & 82.8
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
which clearly has a negative element.
Claim 2
Using the same $X$ and $X_\mathrm{recon}$, we see that the row sums of the first rows clearly differ.

I suppose the relevant follow up question is this: Is claim (2) true in the special case where $X$ is sampled from the probability simplex (i.e., rows are probability profiles). At first glance, the answer seems to be NO. But why?
